# How to add my custom jQuery in admin uiComponent form

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, jquery

Is there any way that I can add a JS/Jquery file which may able to listen my uicomponent's (checkbox/Radio) event (like OnClick or OnChange) so that I can do some operation with that.
That UiComponent i used for an admin form (mentioned below). Please help me on how to add a js/jquery in admin uiComponent form.
Actually I want to avoid knockoutJS because of its complexity and lengthy process.

**my_uicomponent_form.xml**

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<fieldset name="checkout_process_options">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="opened" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Checkout Process Settings</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <field name="main_data">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">SHasan\MyModule\Model\Source\Data\MainData</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Main Data</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">radioset</item>
                    <item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>                        
                </item>
        </argument>
    </field>        
    <field name="secondary_options">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">SHasan\MyModule\Model\Source\Data\SecondaryOptions</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Secondary Options</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkboxset</item>
                    <item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>                        
                </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
    <field name="optional_options">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">SHasan\MyModule\Model\Source\Data\OptionalOptions</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Optional Options</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkboxset</item>
                    <item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>                        
                </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that by using a .phtml file (for writing your JQuery/JS code) and linking it with your UI component inside the layout file.
Inside **view/adminhtml/layout/frontname_controller_action.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="YourUIcomponent"/>
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template" name="fieldname" template="Vendor_Extension::Yourtemplatefile.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        
    </body>
</page>
```

Then create a template file and write your JQuery/JS code in the script tags
**view/adminhtml/templates/Yourtemplatefile.phtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
---Your code---
</script>
```

Hopefully, this info is useful.